# drawRect in UTableViewCell subview only works when cell is selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a custom `UIView` that draws a few lines in its `drawRect` method. I then create a regular `UITableViewCell` and add my custom `UIView` to it.The drawing code in my custom `UIView` will only show when the table view cell is selected. As soon as its deselected all the lines disappear.

I have forced `setNeedsDisplay` to be called multiple times at runtime just to test. Unfortunately, this makes no difference. When the cell is not selected, the lines don't show.

Any ideas?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = createEmptyCell()
        let selectionView = SelectionView(frame: cell.bounds)
        childSelectionView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        cell.addSubview(childSelectionView)
        return cell
}
```

Here is the drawRect method on an empty class

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    super.drawRect(rect)
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 20,y: 50))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2 - 4, y: 50))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2, y: 58))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2 + 4, y: 50))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.width - 20,y: 50))
    path.lineWidth = 1
    UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
    path.stroke()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be something else to this. I just tested this with Xcode 7.2.1 and Swift 2.2 on iOS 9.2 and it works as expected (the red line in this image).

[image]

Keep in mind that The difference between your view when it's selected and when it's not is that when it's selected, the table view will set your view's background color to clear so that it will display the `backgroundView`. Then your view's color is restored when the cell is no longer selected. It does this with all views on the `contentView`'s hierarchy. I made the test view's background color in the storyboard a transparent red to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting some code.

First, you call a method named `createEmptyCell()`. That's probably the wrong thing to do. You must be using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier()` to get your cell. Just call it directly from the `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` delegate method.

Second, never add a subview to a cell from `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`. Once you are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier()` you'll be reusing cells, and you'll be adding the same view over and over, causing both visual and performance problems.

You want to subclass `UITableViewCell` and add your subview in the `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)` or in a prototype cell in your storyboard or laded from a xib file.

I haven't tested your `drawRect()` code, but it looks like it should work fine. If you want to post a sample project on GitHub I'd be happy to help you debug it.